# Temporarily increase the limit on space size?

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I often see those warnings about "overfull \hbox" when I'm preparing my document. Because the document is still in the early stage, I see no point in correcting them on-the-spot - since the document will change anyway.

But I also want to get rid of that ugly overflow (by increasing the possible width of space between words), so I can show that draft to somebody.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: perhaps `\emergencystretch[=]<dimen>`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

TeX has a primitive parameter for that kind of situation: `\emergencystretch`, of which Knuth writes in the TeXbook chapter 14

> If you want to avoid overfull boxes at all costs without trying to fix them
>   manually, you might be tempted to set `\tolerance=10000`; this allows
>   arbitrarily bad lines to be acceptable in tough situations. But infinite
>   tolerance is a bad idea, because TEX doesn’t distinguish between terribly bad
>   and preposterously horrible lines. Indeed, a tolerance of 10000 encourages TEX
>   to concentrate all the badness in one place, making one truly unsightly line
>   instead of two moderately bad ones, because a single “write-off” produces
>   fewest total demerits according to the rules. There’s a much better way to get
>   the desired effect: TEX has a parameter called `\emergencystretch` that is added
>   to the assumed stretchability of every line when badness and demerits are computed, in cases where overfull boxes are otherwise unavoidable. If
>   `\emergencystretch` is positive, TEX will make a third pass over a paragraph
>   before choosing the line breaks, when the first passes did not find a way to
>   satisfy the `\pretolerance` and `\tolerance`. The effect of `\emergencystretch`
>   is to scale down the badnesses so that large infinities are distinguishable
>   from smaller ones. By setting `\emergencystretch` high enough (based on
>   `\hsize`) you can be sure that the `\tolerance` is never exceeded; hence
>   overfull boxes will never occur unless the line-breaking task is truly
>   impossible.

So you could use, for example

```
\emergencystretch=.5em
```

Answer (score 13):

LaTeX has a declaration `\sloppy` for this use, it sets `\emergencystretch` but also some of the other relevant parameters, it is defined as

```
\def\sloppy{%
  \tolerance=9999
  \emergencystretch=3em
  \hfuzz .5pt
  \vfuzz=\hfuzz}
```

So in addition to  increasing `\emergencystretch` it increases `\tolerance` (to allow line breaking that causes greater "badness") and to increase `\hfuzz` and `\vfuzz` so TeX does not warn about overfull boxes unless they are more than half a point overfull.