# How can I make LaTeX break the word at the end of line more beautiful?

Tags: hyphenation

For some reason, I would like to output a very small page pdf file, like 2.7in * 4.5in. However, with such a small page layout, there are words in the last of some lines is always outside the text area. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[
showframe,
paperwidth=2.75in,
paperheight=4.9in,
left=0.1in,
right=0.1in,
top=0.1in,
bottom=0.18in,
footskip=10pt
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
PMI® is the leader and the most widely recognized organization in terms of promoting project management best practices. PMI® strives to maintain and endorse standards and ethics in this field and offers publications, training, seminars, chapters, special interest groups, and colleges to further the project management discipline.
\end{document}
```

Is there anyway I can make it more aligned? Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: With such a narrow text block width, often left-alignment can look better than full justification. Otherwise, `\usepackage{microtype}` (read the package documentation for recommendations and settings) can improve the appearance (sorry, I'm not using a machine with a TeX installation at the moment, so I can't test it myself).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Temporarily increase the limit on space size?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52850/5764)

Comment: Compare the two answers below (using `\sloppy` and `microtype`, respecticely) without the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package. The `microtype` version presumably looks more even on the right margin than the `sloppy` version, even though some of the signs transcend the border.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `microtype` package and/or modify \emergencystretch:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
showframe,
paperwidth=2.75in,
paperheight=4.9in,
left=0.1in,
right=0.1in,
top=0.1in,
bottom=0.18in,
footskip=10pt
]{geometry}

\setlength\emergencystretch{3em}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
PMI® is the leader and the most widely recognized organization in terms of promoting project management best practices. PMI® strives to maintain and endorse standards and ethics in this field and offers publications, training, seminars, chapters, special interest groups, and colleges to further the project management discipline.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think both solution works fine, but this solution I can mirco-modify the emergencystretch, which will give me more choices. Thank you!

Comment: In this case,  the `\emergencystretch` without `microtype` seem enough.

Comment: yes I'm not sure why @MartinSchröder  edited the answer to highlight microtype only

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Then why don't you edit your answer to explain your code more? I dislike code-only answers.

Answer (score 5):

Add the declaration `\sloppy` to your preamble. Moreover, you should use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble because of the registered-trade-mark sign that is invisible otherwise (you may have to replace `utf8` by your encoding).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage
  [showframe,
   paperwidth=2.75in,
   paperheight=4.9in,
   left=0.1in,
   right=0.1in,
   top=0.1in,
   bottom=0.18in,
   footskip=10pt
  ]{geometry}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
PMI® is the leader and the most widely recognized organization in
terms of promoting project management best practices. PMI® strives to
maintain and endorse standards and ethics in this field and offers
publications, training, seminars, chapters, special interest groups,
and colleges to further the project management discipline.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does works, but the output seems a little loose for the text. Thank you. I will read the inputenc package to see if there is any better solutions.

Comment: +1 for noticing the R, I'd better update my answer!

Comment: @CoeusWang If you want to keep the registered-trademark-sign but don't want to enable a particular input encoding, use the `\textregistered` command, i.e., drop the line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and replace the two occurrences of `® ` by `\textregistered\ `.

Comment: `\sloppy` is never a solution, *especially not* in the preamble. `ragged2e` would be much better.

Comment: @gernot, Thanks a lot for your remind! Yes I know to use \textregistered in text, since this is not the focus point for this question, I didn't implement it in the MWE. :)